# SVG: text indentation/space issue on last tspan in group of tspan elements

Tags: html, svg, text, tspan

This code inserts white space on the last of a group of tspan elements, causing the last line of text to fall out of alignment (on the x-axis).

If you add/remove tspan elements from the group, the last line of text always exhibits this behavior.

What's causing this extra white space or indentation?

Code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vvyZaj

```
<svg id="textBox1" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="300">
  <rect class="background" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="gray" />

  <text class="textLines" x="0" y="0">
        <tspan x="100" dy="0.6em" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">tspan line 0</tspan>
        <tspan x="100" dy="1.2em" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">tspan line 1</tspan>
        <tspan x="100" dy="1.2em" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">tspan line 2</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks so much. please post as an answer so you get credit. removing all spaces between the tspan elements fixed this. but is it okay to maintain the newlines between the <text> start and end elements? it looks okay so far, but not sure if this is correct. thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace collapses in SVG and HTML by default, i.e. multiple contiguous whitespace converts to a single space within text or no space at all at the beginning and the end.

You have a complicated layout though you don't realise it where the text in the `<tspan>` elements has various CSS properties that affect its alignment both vertically and horizontally but the whitespace surrounding it does not. That whitespace will however affect layout.

The simplest thing to do would be to remove all the whitespace that's within the `<text>` elements that's not also within a `<tspan>` element.